# how to initiallize variable sized integer array with 0 in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

How can I initialize all the values of array with zero value when the array size is a variable ?

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int a[n] = {0};
```

I tried the upper code but it is giving an error.

Comment: if `n` isn't `constexpr` this won't compile, but this is how you initialize an array's elements to zero.

Comment: Please share the error so we can help.

Comment: `std::vector<int> a(n);`

Comment: the memory required for an array is determined at compile time, while the value of `n` is only available at run-time. to solve this issue, you'll have to use either `std::vector` which can dynamically be re-sized automatically or use manual memory management to allocate enough space for your buffer. but the best way would be to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 3):

Variable sized arrays not allowed in C++. Variable size means the size can be changed while the program is running.. The code above is an attempt to let the user determine the size of a at runtime.

So the code will not compile.

Two alternatives:

```
1. Use Vectors

Example:

   vector<int> a(n,0);

2. Create variable arrays using dynamic memory allocation.

    int*a;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    a = new int[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n;i++)
        *(a+i) = 0;
    delete [] a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable length arrays are not valid C++, although some compilers do implement them as an extension.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Input n
int n;
cin>>n;

// Declare a pointer 
int * a;
// Allocate memory block
a = new int[n];

/* Do stuff */

// Deallocate memory
delete[] a;
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) for more information.